# Ошибка "Required : Editable, Found : String?" Android Studio (Kotlin)

Tags: android, строки, kotlin

Всем привет. Выдает ошибку, и никак не могу разобраться:
`Required : Editable Found : String?`

Код:

```
class GalleryFragment : Fragment() {

    private val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
    
    // other code
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        currentUser?.let { user ->
           Glide.with(this)
               .load(user.photoUrl)
               .into(image_view)
            edit_text_name.setText(user.displayName)
            text_email.text = user.email // <-- ругается на user.email
            text_phone.text = if(user.phoneNumber.isNullOrEmpty()) "Add Number" else user.phoneNumber // так же ругается на user.phoneNumber
        }

        // other code
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том, что `text_email.text` принимает `Editable`, а не `String`, поэтому вы не можете передать строку. Можете использовать это решение:

```
text_email.text = Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable(user.email)
```

Но более правильным и простым решением будет использовать метод

```
text_email.setText(user.email)
```

Comment: Блин, точно! Поле text_email у меня EditText, все правильно... Спасибо!

Comment: Ставьте лайк, подписывайтесь на канал, ссылки в описании=))) Пожалуйста=))) 